# Json error: missing ] after element list

Tags: jquery, json, append

While trying to pass part of a Json string to a function I get the following error:

> missing ] after element list

The Json string looks like :-

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1, name: "254201075698", series: [
            { 
                name: "", 
                reference: "254201075698",
                note: "A test note", 
                color: "#f0f0f0" 
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        id: 2, name: "254201075699", series: [
            { 
                name: "", 
                reference: "254201075699",
                note: "A test note", 
                color: "#e0e0e0" 
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

In a for loop I'm trying to do the following :-

```
item.append(jQuery("<div>", {
                    "class": "",
                    "css": { ""}
                }).append('<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="View details on '+data[i].name+'" onClick="showInfoDialog('+data[i].series+');return false;">'+data[i].name+'</a>'));
```

But the showInfoDialog parameter seems to be throwing the error, I'm not sure why, any ideas?

showInfoDialog looks like :-

```
function showInfoDialog(data) {    
    console.log(data);    
    clearMessages();
    var html ='';
    var id = data.id;           
    html += '<p><label for="client">Reference: </label> '+data.reference+'</p>';
    $('#dialogContainer').html(html);
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('.dialogDiv').dialog('option', 'title', data.reference);
    $(".dialogDiv").dialog('open');
}
```

For loop :-

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

}
```

Comment: what does your `showInfoDialog()` function look like?

Comment: Added more detail for showInfoDialog()

Comment: That `data` is not JSON, it is simply a JavaScript literal, there is a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this....

```
 onClick="showInfoDialog('+data[i].series+')
```

It will just convert it to `showInfoDialog([object Object])` -- you need to **jsonify** data[i].series -- or better still, just attach an `click` event.

```
jQuery('<a href="javascript:" title="View details on '+data[i].name+'">')
    .html(data[i].name)
    .click(function() {
        showInfoDialog(data[i].series);
    })
    .wrap('<div></div>')
    .appendTo(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`onClick="showInfoDialog('+data[i].series+');return false;">'` ...
```

the data[i].series is an array, but it doesn't seem like you're using it as an array in your showInfoDialog() function:

Answer (score 1):

`blah blah blah ... onClick="showInfoDialog('+data[i].series+'); ... blah blah blah`

This is where your error is.

`data[i].series` is an array object.  It gets converted to text using toString, which by defaults outputs "[object object]" or something of that sort.  You need to convert that array into JSON first (e.g. JSON.stringify).

Or, you can do this:

`blah blah blah ... onClick="showInfoDialog(data[' + i + '].series); ... blah blah blah`

It will just be looking for a global variable called "data" (assuming your `var data` is globally accessible).  For example, if i=42, the string will become:

`blah blah blah ... onClick="showInfoDialog(data[42].series); ... blah blah blah`

Comment: +1 for "Json.Stringify" better yet use the event attach/bind method jquery gives you

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using a for-in loop, and I'm assumiming its to iterate over the `data` array.

You should never use a for-in to iterate over an array as you will most likely return the members of the Array base-class as well as the array elements itself. Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fQMYF/1/)

Code:

```
for (var x in data){
    alert(data[x]); //shed-loads of alerts!
}

for (var x in data){
    //can use this
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(x)){
        alert(data[x]);
    }
}

//best just iterate with a standard for loop
for (var x=0; x<data.length; x++){
    alert(data[x]);
}
```

Use a `for` loop that loops from 0 to data.length (as above)